# Use woocommerce product attribute to set a value for minimum and step quantity

Tags: woocommerce

Good morning, I am trying to set a minimum value and quantity steps of products based on an attribute using this code (but it does not work) :

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 ); // Simple products

    function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
        if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
            $args['input_value']    = $attribute["Ordine_minimo"];    // 
    }
        
    $args['min_value']  = $attribute["Ordine_minimo"];    // Minimum value
    $args['step']       = $attribute["Ordine_minimo"];    // Quantity steps
    return $args;
}
```

The Attribute name is Ordine minimo.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter you are using is correct and you are modifying the correct arguments, however, `$attribute["Ordine_minimo"]` is not declared in your code.

Use the given `$product` object to find your attribute:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
    function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
        $value = $product->get_attribute("Ordine_minimo");
        if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
            $args['input_value'] = $value;
        }
            
        $args['min_value'] = $value;    // Minimum value
        $args['step'] = $value;    // Quantity steps
        return $args;
    }
```

Comment: It works, but I had to modify this line

$value = $product->get_attribute("Ordine_minimo");

in 

$value = $product->get_attribute("Ordine minimo"); 

deleting the underscore

Thank you

Comment: @Giak Glad I could help you. Please consider upvoting my answer or accepting it through the checkmark button so other people can find it easier in the future.